# show debit-credit in listview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am from PHP background.Now i have to develop a windows form application using c#. I want to add dynamically rows in the datagridview as follows:

```
Debit/Credit       Ledger Name                Debit Amt         Credit Amt
  Dr               Ledger 1                     500                            
  Cr               Ledger 2                                        500
```

My question is how do i add rows in the above fashion dynamically. Any help with code snippet would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Where is the data coming from?

Comment: Its coming from an entry form

Answer (score 0):

```
DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)nameOfYourGrid.Rows[0].Clone();
row.Cells[0].Value = "Dr";
row.Cells[1].Value = "Ledger 1";
row.Cells[2].Value = 500.0;
row.Cells[3].Value = 0.0;
yourDataGridView.Rows.Add(row);
```

Or instead of using indexes for Cells, you can call them by your column name. I don't know your column name but that should be easy for you to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Add("Dr", "Ledger 1", "500.0", "0.0");
```

Dynamically:

```
private void btnSubmit_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add
    (
        txtDebitCredit.Text,
        txtLedgerName.Text,
        txtDebitAmount.Text,
        txtCreditAmount.Text
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try below approach.

Create you entity class as below to map the data,

```
public class MyEntity
    {
        [DisplayName("Debit/Credit")]
        public string Type
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        [DisplayName("Ledger Name")]
        public string LedgerName
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        [DisplayName("Debit Amt")]
        public int DebitAmount
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        [DisplayName("Credit Amt")]
        public int CreditAmount
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
```

Then populate the data into the entity. I have hard coded,

```
//Populate data - Could be populated from any source
            var myData = new List<MyEntity>();
            myData.Add(new MyEntity() { Type = "Dr", LedgerName = "Ledger Name 1", CreditAmount = 500, DebitAmount = 0 });
            myData.Add(new MyEntity() { Type = "Cr", LedgerName = "Ledger Name 2", CreditAmount = 0, DebitAmount = 500 });

            dataGridView1.DataSource = myData;
```

I would suggest further reading and exploring how DataGridView can be used.

[Bind Data to the Windows Forms DataGridView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/fbk67b6z(v=vs.100).aspx)